# Mongodb find - or operator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have little bit complicated situation -

```
User.find({ isNew: true, isYellow: true, isBlue: true })
           ^^^required            ^^^^^^^^^^^ one of them must be TRUE
```

as you can see above, `isYellow` or `isBlue` must be `true`. I can't use `$or` here, because its about two keys, not two values in one key.

**Question**: How to make query find all users with `isNew === true` and `isYellow` OR `isBlue` **true**?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or) works with query expressions, not values, so it works fine for your case:

```
User.find({ isNew: true, $or: [{isYellow: true}, {isBlue: true}] })
```